# How can I make the rendered block match its HTML source?

Tags: blocks, theming

I have entered HTML into the body of a block with the Full HTML filter (with all filtering disabled).  I am using CKEditor with ACF completely disabled.  The editor shows me the source rendered the way I would expect, but when I save it and view the block in a node (a default, out-of-the-box Basic Page), the block no longer renders the same, various styling attributes are being ignored.  If I open the block again for editing, the source is unchanged, so I know it's not being modified after I save it.  How can I make the block rendering match its source?

Related: my goal here is to be able to enter static, arbitrary HTML and have it render.  Is there a better way to do this? (even if there is, I'd still like an answer to the main question)

Comment: Full HTML still has safeguards on it, take a look at your input filters at `admin/config/content/formats`

Comment: I corrected the Q as I had disabled all the filtering on Full HTML. When a piece of input gets filtered by any of the applied input filters, does that happen before it's saved to the db, or is that a display-time only effect? I still see the same HTML when I edit the block, if it were being filtered, would that remove it from the node source completely, or just not allow it to be displayed?

Comment: Filtering happens on render, not on save.  CKEditor has some functions that edit markup before save but it sounds like you have those turned off.